# How to properly reference a library in nuget-based architecture

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to create couple nuget packages for internal company use:
`OurCompany.Infrastructure.Logging.Interfaces` and just `OurCompany.Infrastructure.Logging`.

So I created two class library projects in the same solution, provided an implementation for `OurCompany.Infrastructure.Logging.Interfaces` and created a package.

Now I have a question: how to properly reference the `OurCompany.Infrastructure.Logging.Interfaces` library in `OurCompany.Infrastructure.Logging` project?

Should I add it as a nuget package or simply add as a project reference?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for the issue? If zivkan's answer resolves your issue you could consider marking it as accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no perfect solution.

When you use a NuGet package but need to make a change in the library while working on an app that uses it, you need to make the change in the library, publish a new version of the package, update your reference in your app, then hope the change you made in the library worked as needed. Particularly when working on a new feature this is very slow because your software design often changes multiple times between when you first start to when you finish, and debugging is more difficult. If your company doesn't have tooling to check for updates and remind teams that updates are available, then you can get into a fragmentation situation with some teams still using very old versions of the library and if they try to upgrade their app breaks and need extra time to adapt to the breaking changes in the shaed library.

On the other hand, if you use project references, debugging and implementing new features is easier, and breaking changes are detected immeidately, assuming you have adequite automated tests, but it requires all the code to be in the same repository, or to look like it does (maybe using git submodules, or have a convention where multiple repos are always clonsed in the same relative path).

Both Google and Microsoft had to implement their own source control system tools to deal with massive repos that are too big for a single developer machine to work with, plus speed up compile times both of dev boxes and on CI agents, because you don't want changing 1 line of code in one app causing every single app the company has being rebuilt and tested. But unless your company wants to dedicate engineers to working on the build system and not contributing to customer applications, this is infeasible.

So, the submodule, or multiple-repos with relative path conventions sounds appealing, but it still requires the library to be recompiled on every CI build that uses the library. Not a big deal, but if the frequency of changing the shared library is very low, there's little benefit to making code changes to the library easy. Plus when someone else updates the library, how will you know that you need to update the submodule? The NuGet tooling is probably better for checking for updates and actually updating.

Personally, I always use project references references for projects that are already in the same solution and nuget references for everything else. What I've done in the past is when I need to either bug fix or add a new feature to the packaged library, I clone both repos side, temporarily add the library's project(s) to my app's solution and change the nuget references to project references. Then I develop as if they're all in one repo. Finally, I need to manually undo the solution/project reference changes and increment the package reference version number before check in. Since it's manual it sometimes goes wrong. But it's the best balance I've found so far. You need to decide on what's best for yor own situation.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is: Do Both!

With the Choose directive, you can set conditional referencing:

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="Path\To\Your.Awesome.Package.csproj" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Your.Awesome.Package" Version="1.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
```

In this example, your project will use the direct project reference while running in Debug mode, then, the rest of the time it will use the NuGet package reference.

Even though you are still responsible for maintaining the proper NuGet package version, nothing is perfect.

I hope this would help somebody.